# Error 50001: Missing Access when trying to register command

Tags: java, discord-jda

I get this error when I try to register the following code:
CODE

```
    @Override
public void onGuildReady(@NotNull GuildReadyEvent event) {
    List<CommandData> commandData = new ArrayList<>();
    commandData.add(Commands.slash("tc", "Test command"));
    event.getGuild().updateCommands().addCommands(commandData).queue();
}
```

Error in image below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to invite your bot to the server with the `applications.commands` scope in the URL.

1. Go to https://discord.com/developers/applications
2. Open your app dashboard for your bot
3. Navigate to OAuth2 > URL Generator
4. Click **bot** and **applications.commands**
5. Scroll down (optionally select a redirect uri if needed) and copy the generated link
6. Open the link and add the bot to your server

This link must be used for *all servers* that you intend to use commands in.

Comment: I already did that, even kicked and re-invited the bot to the server (with that link) and still get that error